# how to sort a column in postgresql and set it to sorted values

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and would like to know how to set a column in a table to its sorted version. For example:

**(table: t1, column: points)**
5
7
3
9
8
4
(**table: t1, column: points)** // pls note it is sorted
3
4
5
7
8
9

My incorrect version:

```sql
UPDATE outputTable SET points_count =  (SELECT points_count FROM outputTable ORDER BY points_count ASC)
```

Comment: Your question says you have a column `points` but your query refers to a column `points_count` - which on is it? And which data type is that column?

Comment: it is an example as mentioned right before, my query is what I use in the program and is incorrect

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand, for a simple explanation I had put the column horizontally.

Comment: Rows in a relational table don't have any implied sort order, so what you are trying to do makes no sense.  If you need the rows in a sorted way, just use `order by` when selecting from the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
UPDATE outputTable 
SET    points_count =  s.points_count
FROM   (SELECT points_count, ctid FROM outputTable ORDER BY points_count ASC) s
WHERE  outputTable.ctid = s.ctid;
```

As you are planning to update same table with reference to same table, you will need row level equality criteria like ctid to update each row.

Comment: Shows an error that s.ctid does not exist

Comment: @Vishwad edited the query, missed the select for ctid, try now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to sort the rows in a table.

Now this is normally a pointless exercise, since tables have no fixed order. In fact, every `UPDATE` will change the order of rows in a PostgreSQL table.

The only way you can get a certain order in the result rows of a query is by using the `ORDER BY` clause, which will sort the rows regardless of their physical order in the table (which is not dependable, as mentioned above).

There is one use case for physically reordering a table: an index range scan using an index on `points_count` will be much more efficient if the table is physically sorted like the index. The reason is that far fewer table blocks will be accessed.

Therefore, there is a way to rewrite the table in a certain order as long as you have an index on the column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON outputtable (points_count);

CLUSTER outputtable USING points_count;
```

But – as I said above – unless you plan a range scan on that index, the exercise is pointless.